# use MyUser to auth in django

Tags: python, django, authentication

Asking for your help, because can't find right answer by myself. I made custom registration form in django with additional fields. To save that fields in database i made custom user in my models. And it works ok(as i understand). But it seems that auth is using the old User model. I have two thoughts:
1- I need to overwrite some method in MyUser.
2- I found some information about adding AUTH_USER_MODEL variable in my settings ( but it call some errors)

forms.py

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    bdate=forms.DateField(required=True)
    phone=forms.CharField(required=True)
    captha=CaptchaField(required=True)


    class Meta:
        model=MyUser
        fields=('username','first_name','last_name','email','bdate','phone','password1','password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.bdate=self.cleaned_data['bdate']
        user.phone=self.cleaned_data['phone']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

models.py

```
class MyUser(User):
    bdate=models.DateField()
    phone=models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: ERRORS:
    app.MyUser.user_ptr: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.

Answer (score 1):

You should not inherit from User, which is a concrete class. Inherit from AbstractUser instead.

Comment: rise error 
OperationalError at /accounts/register/

no such column: app_myuser.username

Comment: When you do what? Have you migrated your database?

Comment: I made migrate. Error appear when i'm tying to register a new user.

Comment: Well the error indicates you have not done the migration. Please execute `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: manage.py migrate working ok, but makemigrations rise errors like that 
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to myuser without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py

Comment: In fact, i don't think that problem is that i inherit User. All that do User class is inherit AbstractUser, and define swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL' in Meta class